# How to add mysql server in Xamp with mysql installer and workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I got xampp installed and I got mysql installer installed some tools without the server. How can I use server installed in xampp from installer and workbench?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clearer?

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim you see I downloaded xampp with mysql server and i also have mysql workbench and installer, How can I start the mysql server in workbench and also how can I tell mysql installer that I already have mysql server installed?

Comment: In the mysql installer, you can choose custom install and pick the tools you want to install. If you already have Workbench and MySQL Server installed, you can just leave those option unchecked in the installer.